# location address using ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to print the location address and last_seen  time in a table like format. Getting the formatted address correctly from `res.location[i].lat, res.location[i].long`. But when I append the `last_seen` to the string , getting only the last record's  value. I mean getting the same value for `last_seen` and that is the last record's value.

Please help me to find out where I am going wrong?

```
function getAddress(res)
{
    var html = '';
    var latitude = '';
    var longitude = '';
    var location_id = '';
    for (i = 0; i < res.location.length; i++){ 
        latitude = res.location[i].lat;
        longitude = res.location[i].long;
        location_id = res.location[i].id;
        var last_seen = moment(res.location[i].created_at).calendar();
        console.log(location_id);
        console.log(last_seen);
        url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+parseFloat(latitude)+','+ parseFloat(longitude)+'&key=AIzaSyCJeRq6PHsq6DOwC3YDeIR1357I3w5BPLI';
        $.ajaxq ('getAddress', {
            url: url,
            type: 'post',
            data: 
            {
                delay: 5
            },
            success: function (response) 
            {
                console.log(last_seen);
                html = '<tr><td>' + response.results[0].formatted_address+'<br />Last Seen : '+ last_seen +'</td><td><input type="checkbox" checked="true" name="selected-location" id="'+location_id +'" value="'+location_id +'"></td></tr>'; 
                $('#single-user tr:last').after(html);

             }
         }); 
    }

}
```

Comment: It might be a cop/paste error, but you're missing the opening brace for your `for`-loop. I also fail to see the relevance of the PHP tag?

Comment: when I copied and indented just missed the opening brace.

Comment: Please update the question so it matches your real code. It's pretty hard to help you with the question if we don't know if there are other copy/paste mistakes as well.

Comment: First console.log(last_seen) logging the correct one. At the time of appending it to string after Geocode api call, its getting wrong.